# swipe left right to chnge activity

Tags: android, swipe

i have three class simple.java, simple1.java, simple2.java

example:

```
package com.finalapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class simple extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

    }

    public void setArguments(Bundle data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

so how to swipe this three class ...

and direct using in tab host type.....

Comment: You can use fragment to achieve it.

Comment: yes, Fragment is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: you can see this link [ http://viewpagerindicator.com/ ] for swipe fragment.the classes you created use as three fragment.you may add more fragment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is the simplest way to do this. You can use Fragments in API level 11 or above.
But using fragments your classes simple, simple1 &simple 2 would no longer extend Activity class. You will have to do like this.

```
sipmle extends Fragment
```

If you do not need your classes to extend Activity class then you can definitely use Fragments
[here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/) is a very nice tutorial you can refer